# Using Maven for modifying an archive

Tags: java, maven

Please help me with evaluation whether maven could be used for a problem I am faced with. Hopefully you can give me some hints on maven or suggest using a different tool.

Problem:
We have a template archive containing resources. We need to create a new archive based on the template using custom files/data.

- some files from the template have to be replaced with custom ones.
- some files have to be processed and placeholders in these files have to be replaced with custom variables. (i.e ${filename} -> "my_file_name.txt")

The pom file should describe which files should be replaced and where custom files should be taken from. Also it should describe which files to be processed by place-holder processor and where to get the variables values.

It is possible to write a java program to do all these stuffs, but Java code must be changed again and again for a different set of custom files and new placeholders. Hopefully with help of maven (also custom plugins if required) this task could be a simple configuration task.

**Example:**

Template folder:

```
/src/main/resources/file1.xml
/src/main/resources/file2.xml
/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

file2.xml:

```
<file>${file_name}</file>
```

Custom folder:

```
/src/main/resources/file1.xml
/src/main/resources2/file3.xml
```

Custom Property File:

```
file_name=my_file_name.xml
```

**Result:**

```
/src/main/resources/file1.xml
/src/main/resources/file2.xml
/src/main/resources2/file3.xml
/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

file2.xml:

```
<file>my_file_name.xml</file>
```

Questions:

1. How to put the unmodified MANIFEST.MF into target folder.
   I tried to use

   <archive>

   <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
      <manifestFile>src/main/resources/template/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>

   </archive>

but it simply disables 'maven' part of the META-INF. The manifiest.mf was still generated by maven

2. How to implement placeholder/variable processor?
3. How to zip the resulting set of files into .zip file?
4. How to invoke a maven build from a java class?
5. Is there an alternative tool which might be more suitable for my task?

regards,
ilia

Comment: Hi Ilia, welcome to Stack Overflow. It is customary to ask a single question per post. It is okay to seek clarification or assistance on multiple points in a single question, so long as they are tightly coupled. In the future, you may consider asking multiple questions in their own right.

Comment: Thanks. I agree it is always better to ask single questions. But currently I am looking rather for advises which tool to use - should it be maven or something else. So please read questions as rather requirements, not the request for detailed help. I just need to know whether maven is the right way to go or rather not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a lot of questions, but I'll try to answer:

1. Move the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF to /src/main/resources/
2. It is already implemented on http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/ for replacing properties on resources files with ${propertyName}
3. Zips can be created with http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/
4. Don't do that, Maven is invoked from command line, IDE or continuous integration server.
5. On tool would be Gradle, or the older Ant for naming some of them.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding 4: the archive generation should be done on the fly. User chooses the template, provides his custom file/variable and click on 'go' button. The server prepares the archive and deploys it. So I need a tool which will prepare the archive for the deployment. I don't have any IDE or continuous integration server.